# PHP osTicket error in Google Chrome

Tags: php, no-data

Occassionally I receive an error when trying to refresh any webpage on the osTicket system. Has anybody experienced similar problems? What did you do to prevent that from happening?

Here's the error:

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
```

I assume it's a session problem, but am not sure because I only installed it on my test server. However, it would be very bad if a customer ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is a standard Google Chrome error. Just as the message describes, the server sent no data to the browser.

This is more likely a server problem than an osTicket one. Make sure your web server is running properly, and check the log files for errors and problems.